# Why does onclick="ShowLocalDate()" only work once, the first one it encounters

Tags: javascript, html

I have three forms in the code below.  The first form passes date just fine, but the other two forms don't pass the date.  The other forms will work fine as well as long as they are the first form called.  So the question is why can I use the `onclick` function only in one form on a page.  all other onclick's are ignored after the first one is called.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Active Profile</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<script>
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('form');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
buttons[i].addEventListener('submit', ShowLocalDate);
}

function ShowLocalDate() {
event.preventDefault();

var dNow = new Date();

var localdate = '[' + (dNow.getMonth() + 1) + ']<' + dNow.getDate() + '>!' +
dNow.getFullYear() + '!-' + dNow.getHours() + '-:' +
dNow.getMinutes() + ':';

event.target.querySelector(".createdAtInput").value = localdate;

event.target.submit();
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<!-- form below works -->
<form action="history_report.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
<button type="submit">X-fer Date</button>
</form>

<!--  does not work -->
<form action="history_report.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
<button type="submit">X-fer Date</button>
</form>

<!-- does not work -->
<form action="modify_refund_script.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
<button type="submit">X-fer Date</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: @RickyT even if `id`s weren't supposed to be unique (it's in the name basically), how is JavaScript supposed to know which `<input>` you're referring to? None of this is good practice, but a quick fix is `onclick="ShowLocalDate(this)"` and `function ShowLocalDate(form){` and `form['php_client_date'] = localdate;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute must be unique in the same document, replace the duplicate once using common classes like :

```
<form action="history_report.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
    <button type="submit">X-fer Date</button>
</form>
```

It will be better to **avoid** the use of inline-event `onClick` and try to attach the event inside your JS code using `addEventListener()` like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Active Profile</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

      for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', ShowLocalDate);
      }
    });

    function ShowLocalDate() {
      event.preventDefault();

      var dNow = new Date();

      var localdate = '[' + (dNow.getMonth() + 1) + ']<' + dNow.getDate() + '>!' +
        dNow.getFullYear() + '!-' + dNow.getHours() + '-:' +
        dNow.getMinutes() + ':';

      event.target.querySelector(".createdAtInput").value = localdate;

      event.target.submit();
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- form below works -->
  <form action="history_report.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
    <button type="submit">X-fer Date</button>
  </form>

  <!--  does not work -->
  <form action="history_report.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
    <button type="submit">X-fer Date</button>
  </form>

  <!-- does not work -->
  <form action="modify_refund_script.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
    <button type="submit">X-fer Date</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it is not working for me.  I added the header script that I am using to my code above, is this my problem?  Your snippet run fine, I just want to understand this.  The first answer above works though, but I would prefer to use this answer as it sound like the proper way

Comment: You're welcome brother, no the header looks just fine, tell me what not working exactly when you rested it and is there any error message in the browser console?

Comment: I just get a complete empty value.  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Try to add `event.target.submit();` at the end, check my update

Comment: Still No go my friend

Comment: Do you have the project deployed somewhere or you're trying locally? I need more information to detect the issue, the form submits or not after the click? and are you sure you've changed the ids with classes in your HTML?

Comment: I updated my original question "code" to what you have told me, look at that and see where I am messing up.

Comment: Try my snippet now using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {`

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Buddy

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody says: ids must be unique. Use classes if you want to target multiple elements.
But (as a fun fact) there is a way to target multiple elements with the same id by limiting scope of the search:

```js
const forms = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("form"));
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`[type="hidden"]`)).forEach(el => el.type = "text");

forms.forEach(form => form.addEventListener("submit", e => e.preventDefault()));
```

```html
<script>

function ShowLocalDate(el){
var dNow = new Date();
var localdate= '['+(dNow.getMonth()+1) + ']<' + dNow.getDate() + '>!' 
+ dNow.getFullYear() + '!-' + dNow.getHours() + '-:' + 
dNow.getMinutes() + ':';
el.parentElement.querySelector("#createdAtInput").value = localdate; // search for the id within a form
}

</script>

<body >

<!-- form below works -->
<form action="history_report.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
<button onclick="ShowLocalDate(this)" type="submit" >X-fer Date</button>
</form>

<!--  does not work -->
<form action="history_report.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
<button onclick="ShowLocalDate(this)" type="submit" >X-fer Date</button>
</form>

<!-- does not work -->
<form action="modify_refund_script.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="createdAtInput" name="php_client_date" />
<button onclick="ShowLocalDate(this)" type="submit" >X-fer Date</button>
</form>
```